# when I try to submit empty form it doesn't showing error it just redirecting on main page

Tags: php, laravel-5.7

when I am submitting empty form it is not validating , and redirecting on home page .I had store validation in a variable and put into "dd($validation)" but when i enter some data in field then only it is show my "dd($validation)" output . whats happening in it i tried to configure please let me know .

output after adding data in field

```
array:1 [▼
  "phone" => "123"
]
```

when I submit empty its redirecting on main page

**controller.php**

```
public function login(Request $request){
   return view('vendor/voyager/mobileverification');
}

public function loginwithNumber(Request $request)
{
    $user = $request->all();
    // dd($user);
    $dd = $request->validate([
        'phone' => 'required|min:11|numeric'
    ]);
    dd($dd);
}
```

**mobileverification.blade.php**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="loginwithNumber" method="POST" action="{{ route('voyager.loginwithnumber') }}">
    @csrf
    <table id="mobilenumber" class="" width="70%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" >
        @if (count($errors) > 0)
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
        @endif
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="tex">Phone No.<p class="info">(OTP will be sent on this number.)</p></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your phone no" name="phone" maxlength="10" id="customer_phone" value="{{ old('phone') }}" autofocus>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: When you submit it empty then it comes in loginwithNumber method?

Comment: yes sir , in login method i had called view, then in view i have given in action as you can see in my code